# How debug react library from react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging

I've one library written in typescript. Library is consumed into my react app as devDependany.
Now, How can i debug library ??

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how it was built, you might be able to see the TS sources in the DevTools in Chrome:

[image]

From there you should be able to set breakpoints